# jqGrid - Default Sort Order by Column

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

Happy New Years Eve!

I would like to be able to set the default for value some columns to descending. So, the first time the user clicks on that column, it sorts descending by nature.

I have no problem setting the default sort field and order of my grid. But that is all the info I am finding.

```
$grid->setGridOptions(array(

"caption"=>"Player Statistics",
"rowNum"=>200,
"rowList"=>array(50,200,1000),
"sortname"=>"percentOwned",
"sortorder" => 'desc',
"width" => 1000,
"height" => 400,
"hoverrows" => true,
"viewrecords" => false

));
```

How do I set the default sort to descending on a per column basis? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  you are exactly right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although not in the documentation, 'firstsortorder' => 'desc' does the trick.

```
$grid->setGridOptions(array(
'firstsortorder' => 'desc'
"caption"=>"Player Statistics",
"rowNum"=>200,
"rowList"=>array(50,200,1000),
"sortname"=>"percentOwned",
"sortorder" => 'desc',
"width" => 1000,
"height" => 400,
"hoverrows" => true,
"viewrecords" => false
));
```

Comment: That looks like it will apply to every column. This attribute also works for each column by setting it in the column's model. I do not know how to do that for the PHP version, however.